# Hierarchical index multi index containing edge values. Rearrange it?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transform, networkx

I have pandas dataframe that contains edge values generated with networkx (centrality, betweeness and etc). 
The (multi) index of each row is named by node source and no target. 
The graph that I have is not directed, so the order of node names in index does not matter to me.
However, for the sake of comparison and other actions, I would like to have the values at the same order.

What is the problem?

```
i1, i2, val1, val2, val3
A,   B,   10,  NaN, 5
B,   A,  NaN,    3,  NaN
```

I think that there are two possible ways to solve this:
A) to mirror the values by reversing the index for every value and NaN value to get the value.
B) to reorder whole dataframe, so that only A->B appears and B->A is never appearing.

A)

```
i1, i2, val1, val2, val3
A,   B,   10,   3,  5
B,   A,   10,   3,  5
```

B)

```
i1, i2, val1, val2, val3
A,   B,   10,  3,  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use solution B since if you don't care about the edge direction and are treating the rows as the same thing, There is no reason to duplicate data.

first merge your indexes into one index using the following

```
uniques = df[['i1','i2']].apply(lambda x:frozenset(x),axis=1)
```

Then just group by your new indexes and merge the values together...

```
df.groupby(uniques).sum()
```

**output**

```
In [133]: df.groupby(uniques).sum()
Out[133]:
        val1  val2  val3
(A, B)    10     3     5
```